# Как лучше реализовать класс для хранения переменных?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, шаблоны-проектирования

В моем проекта для хранения глобальных переменных я использую класс `Config` вида:

```
class Config:
    # Colors
    WHITE = Color(255, 255, 255)
    STAR_COLOR = Color(255, 255, 17)
    PLANET_COLOR = Color(0, 255, 0)
    DARK_BLUE = Color(0, 6, 15)
    TRANSPARENT = Color(0, 0, 0, 0)

    BUTTON_GREEN = Color(47, 191, 113)
    BUTTON_RED = Color(239, 45, 86)

    # Window
    WIDTH = 1280
    HEIGHT = 720
    WINDOW_SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    FPS = 120
    STABLE_FPS = 100

    ....
```

Правильный ли это поход? Может быть стоит переместить все переменные в `__init__` и затем создать единственный экземпляр класса `Config` и в дальнейшем при импорте использовать именно экземпляр класса, а не сам класс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю насколько это правильный подход, но я бы для этой цели воспользовался модулем `enum`.

Пример:

```
import enum

class Colors(enum.Enum):
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

print(Colors.BLUE.value)

for i in Colors:
    print(i.name)
    print(i.value)
```

Вот статья с достаточно неплохим [объяснением по этой теме](https://habr.com/ru/company/timeweb/blog/564826/).